# Mapping UK river gauges / stations

Tags: data, hydrology, united-kingdom

Do you know a way to map all the river gauges / stations in UK? 
I found some data from the Environment Agency but it lacks of the longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you need the data for, the following links may or may not be helpful.

You may find useful data from the National River Flow Archive (NRFA), part of the Centre for Ecology & Hydrology: http://www.ceh.ac.uk/data/nrfa/
As far as I can tell they do not have GIS formats available to download.

This website, made by Shoothill, maps river gauges in the UK and gets its data from the Environment Agency: http://www.gaugemap.co.uk/

Shoothill has an API which is provided under the Open Government license (make sure you read it before using the API): http://www.shoothill.com/environment-agency-liveapi/

Answer (score 1):

The new Environment Agency API provides lat/lng for stations, though in England only: http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference#stations

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say this has already been done, but @juturna and @owenboswarva beat me to it.

If you do want to go ahead and do this your own way, it sounds like [geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) is the way forward. There should be enough [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806548/geocode-area-names-of-a-city-to-get-lat-and-long) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11450/disambiguate-messy-place-names-in-python-preferably-on-local-machine) to get you started.

Answer (score -2):

I work with [eZhing.com](http://www.ezhing.com)

1. Put Gauges on the layout
2. Transfer data in real time with JSON full rest